# Django running wrong version

Tags: python, django, mediatemple

Although running "python" from the shell runs Python v2.7, Django is loading files for python2.4, as shown in the error when I load a django site:

> Mod_python error: "PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 287, in HandlerDispatch
>      log=debug)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 461, in import_module
>       f, p, d = imp.find_module(parts[i], path)
>
> ImportError: No module named django

I think Django is installed for version 2.7 and that's why the bottom says "No module named django"

This is my first django install (it's on a mediatemple DV server) so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm doing something stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently `python` resolves to `/usr/lib/python2.4`. You'll need to make sure `python` resolves to wherever you've got Python 2.7 installed by adjusting your system path.

Comment: @Dominic: mod_python doesn't care where `python` points or what version it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_python is built for 2.4, but Django is installed for 2.7. Either build mod_python for 2.7, install Django under 2.4, or put a local copy of Django with your project so that the version of Python doesn't matter.

Comment: How do I build mod_python for 2.7?

Comment: Dunno. The docs that come with it should explain how to rebuild it. But since this is a VPS you should consider using mod_wsgi instead seeing as how it's not, you know, dead.

Comment: Once I install mod_wsgi what is required to link that to my django install?

Comment: You don't. You install mod_wsgi and Django for the same version of Python, and they find each other.

Comment: Now when I go to my root of my django install it says "403 forbidden" -- any ideas how that link broke?